# Crashing after 10 minutes of gameplay

Tags: swift, xcode6, sprite-kit, crash-reports, skemitternode

The app is using an SKEmitterNode (please see my question about this below)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31991350/skemitternode-not-acting-consistently

The particles don't emit consistently. In the scene where the particles don't emit, about ten minutes into gameplay the app crashes, with this error: Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1,subcode=0x1004cd474)

then the particles emit every time no fail. Whats going wrong??

Comment: You can profile your App using Instruments, maybe you can find some memory leak or something weird with the graphics

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem sourced to a single zPosition in another function causing the emitter to be either hidden underneath or causing app to crash.